# Trouble understanding difference between disk and drives

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, desktop-computer, storage

So I'm studying for the A+ and we are currently learning about RAID configurations. It says Raid 0 requires 2 disk while Raid requires 2 drives. However wouldn't Raid 0 still require two drives because each drive contain separate disk? Can you have two disk on one separate drive. Also what disk is used in SSD? Need help better understanding the difference between the two

Comment: Disk and drive are the same thing. You are probably thinking about PARTITIONS?

Comment: https://www.techolac.com/computers/what-is-the-difference-between-a-disk-and-a-drive/  it says here disk is more digital storage media while drive is the physical part unless I'm understanding it wrong

Comment: Such distinctions are irrelevant in the context - RAID - of your question.

Comment: All HDDs have multiple disks (as in "plates") inside, so what? Yes, SSDs don't have any, they're all chips inside. Again, why does it matter?

Comment: To understand RAID, forget about definitions for disks and drives for a minute and consider that in order to stripe data (RAID 0) you need 2 storage devices regardless if those devices are hard drives or solid state drives. For RAID 1, to mirror you need two. For RAID 5 you will need at least 3 so you can reconstruct a failing drive using parity from the other two. IMO you're concentrating on the wrong thing although I can understand your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In this context Disk and Drive are being used interchangeably.   They are the same thing.